# Kotlin: how to get the date from a MM/yy formatted input?

Tags: kotlin, date

How do I parse strings of the MM/yy format (ex: 12/22) to kotlin date objects ? Can a date object even exist without a day value ? I've tried the following :

```
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.util.Locale
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder


fun main() {
    var str_date = "06/22"
    
    val df: DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendPattern("MM/yy")
    .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
    
    println(LocalDate.parse(str_date, df))
}
```

which results in the following exception:

`java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '06/22' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {Year=2022, MonthOfYear=6},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Java `LocalDate` requires a day, month, and year, so it can't parse `06/22`.

If you need to parse only a month and year, then there's [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html)

```kotlin
import java.time.YearMonth
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder
import java.util.Locale

fun main() {
  val monthYearFormatter = DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendPattern("MM/yy")
    .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH)

  // prints 2022-06
  println(YearMonth.parse("06/22", monthYearFormatter))

  // error: Invalid value for MonthOfYear (valid values 1 - 12): 13
  println(YearMonth.parse("13/22", monthYearFormatter))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit the answer and sorry to post a wrong answer before.

And as the error shows `LocalDate` need infomation about `date` which`'MM/yy'` not complete include.

So 3 answers below:

1. `YearMonth` is a better choice to format that pattern. you can get a `YearMonth` then choice a `day` to get a `LocalDate`
2. set a default `day_of_month` to `LocalDate`
3. get a `java.util.Date` then get a `LocalDate`

```kotlin
    // 1
    val fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/yy")
    val ym = YearMonth.parse("12/22", fmt)
    val dt = ym.atEndOfMonth()
    println(dt)// 2022-12-31

    // 2
    val fmt2 = DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendPattern("MM/yy")
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
        .toFormatter()
    val dt2 = LocalDate.parse("12/22", fmt2)
    println(dt2)// 2022-12-01

    // 3 get a java.util.Date
    val fmt3 = SimpleDateFormat("MM/yy")
    val dt3 = fmt3.parse("12/22")
    println(dt3)  // Thu Dec 01 00:00:00 CST 2022
```

Comment: This code returns the following error `Text '12/22' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {Year=2022, MonthOfYear=12},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed`